# Testing a function which has multiple autowired classes in a nested manner using Mockito

Tags: unit-testing, testing, junit, mocking, mockito

Here I want to test `method1`. I wanted to implement it using `@Mock` and `@InjectMocks` annotations, but using the `class B` as mock, it returns NPE.

```
 class A {
     @Autowired
     private B b;

     public String method1()
       {
         return b.method2(); 
       }
     }

class B{
     @Autowired
     private C c;

    public String method2(){
       return C.method3();
     }
    }
```

Test class :

```
@InjectMocks
    A a;

    @Mock
    B b = new B();


    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void testMethod1() {

    String x=a.method1();
    assertEquals("value",x);
    }
```

Comment: can you show your test class / method?

Comment: @MaciejKowalski please check now

Answer (score 0):

When using `@Mock` annotation, do not instantiate the variable manually.

Mockito will do it for you, otherwise you end up with the normal instance instead of a mock:

```
@Mock
B b;
```

Also make sure you set-up you mock in some way to expect a certain value:

```
doReturn(returnString).when(b).method2();
```

Answer (score 0):

To invoke `C` real method use [@Spy](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.22.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#21) in test class

```
@Spy
@Autowired
private C c;
```

> Note that @InjectMocks can also be used in combination with the @Spy annotation, it means that Mockito will inject mocks into the partial mock under test.

Also notice a [warning](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.24.0/org/mockito/Spy.html) about using `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)` with `@Spy`:

> if you call MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this) in a super class constructor then this will not work. It is because fields in subclass are only instantiated after super class constructor has returned. It's better to use @Before. Instead you can also put initMocks() in your JUnit runner (@RunWith) or use the built-in [MockitoJUnitRunner](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.24.0/org/mockito/junit/MockitoJUnitRunner.html).